# How to access items from a ListView SimpleCursorAdaptor

Tags: android, android-listview

I am loading a listview with 2 columns using a SimpleCursorAdaptor.  The code is:

```
        mCursor = managedQuery(MyobiliseData.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

    //3. Attach the data to the listview using an adaptor
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.list_item_custom_font, 
            mCursor, 
            new String[]{MyobiliseData.Columns.CUSTOMER_NAME,MyobiliseData.Columns.ADDRESS},
            new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
            );
     listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When an item in the list is selected I am trying to access the data, but I am not sure what type of object to use - when I use a HashMap object, it fails, i.e.

```
HashMap<String, String> item =  (HashMap<String,String>) listView1.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Any help most appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get item on a particular index from cursor, use as follows:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
    {
         mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
         String customerName=mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyobiliseData.Columns.CUSTOMER_NAME));
         String address=mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyobiliseData.Columns.ADDRESS));
         //Use CustomerName and address
    }
});
```